# VueJS - List Array and Show/Hide Independently

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm trying to figure how to make each of my items listed, independently be hidden and show, currently when you open one the other opens as well. Would I need to use an index of some sort? I am using v-show because I need the content to be rendered before hand and hidden on load but shown on click.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in items" :key="item">
            {{ item.title }}

            <div v-if="item.examples != null">
                <a v-on:click="visibleExample = !visibleExample">Example</a>
                <transition name="fade">
                    <div v-show="visibleExample">
                        <div v-for="example in item.examples" :key="example">
                            {{ example }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </transition>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                visibleExample: false,
                items: [{
                        title: 'Title',
                        examples: [
                            'Question',
                            'Answer'
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'ABC',
                        examples: [
                            '1',
                            '2',
                            '3',
                            '4',
                            '5'
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Please note: This is a stripped version of my original code for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

You could to use a new aux list of items and there can append a new `boolean` property for each object of item list. Then you could use `auxItems` on your `v-for` as below:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          title: 'Title',
          examples: [
            'Question',
            'Answer'
          ]
        },
        {
          title: 'ABC',
          examples: [
            '1',
            '2',
            '3',
            '4',
            '5'
          ]
        }
     ],
      auxItems: []
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.auxItems = this.items.map(i => ({ ...i, isVisible: false }))
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in auxItems" :key="item.title" class="item">
    {{ item.title }}
    <div v-if="item.examples !== null">
      <a v-on:click="item.isVisible = !item.isVisible">Example</a>
      <transition name="fade">
        <div v-show="item.isVisible">
          <div v-for="example in item.examples" :key="example">
            {{ example }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your idea, I tried doing it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/MrCarrasco/doqfbts6/ but got lost in between. The Jsfiddle currently only shows the items but not independently. My goal was to try to keep this as clean as possible. I will change this into vue component form and bundle with webpack if I get this to work later.

Comment: looks well but you should iterate the property `item.examples` with `v-for` inside of the child component.

Answer (score 1):

You've got three main options:

1. Use an array of booleans for `visibleExample`, paired up with your `items` by index. The pairing could either be performed in the template using an index from the `v-for` or the two arrays could be 'merged' using a computed property.
2. Add a boolean property to each of your `items` that holds whether or not the example should be shown for that particular item.
3. Extract a separate component to represent an item. This could include everything in the `v-for` or just the example portion. Either way there'd be a `visibleExample` property in the `data`, with each component holding its own state. This is often the best solution but it can get fiddly if you need the `visibleExample` state outside the component. For the code in the question this wouldn't be a problem but it would depend on what the full code looked like.

Comment: Which would be the simplest option to implement? 3, a separate component?

Comment: @Charles There isn't really enough information in the question to answer that. Any of them could be implemented in under 5 minutes. I would suggest trying all of them if you aren't clear exactly what each entails. Option 2 is probably the simplest given the code in the question but in practice it might involve combining server-side data and UI state in one data structure, which can make it fiddly. The component boundary introduced by option 3 is useful to solve this problem but it can be an obstacle if data subsequently needs passing across it.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, one way to solve it is to keep track of the current selected item.

This can be achieved  by doing this:

```html
<div v-if="item.examples != null">
   <a v-on:click="visibleExample = !visibleExample; crtSelectedItem = item">Example</a>
   <transition name="fade">
    <div v-show="visibleExample && item.id === crtSelectedItem.id">
        <div v-for="example in item.examples" :key="example">
           {{ example }}
        </div>
     </div>
   </transition>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried this word for word and the result I need was not achieved.